# Float div inside another div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make a `div` `float: right` inside another `div` but it does not work? I need help, Here is my code:

```css
.next-week {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: green;
}

.next-week .next-icon {
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.sche-content .next-week .next-icon p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="next-week">
  <div class="next-icon">
    <p>Next week</p>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/barenahiru/edit?html,css,output

Comment: try using 'justify-content: flex-end' instead of 'float: right'. No need to float things when using flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to change the attribute in css like this,

```
.next-week {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flow-root; // Changed the display style
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `display: flex` so use `margin-left: auto;` to make float right in child div

```css
.next-week {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: green;
}

.next-week .next-icon {
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.sche-content .next-week .next-icon p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="next-week">
  <div class="next-icon">
    <p>Next week</p>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Floats are ignored in flex containers. 
So, if you get rid of the flex, and then clear it with a pseudo element, you'll get it on the right :-)

```
 .next-week {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
   /* display: flex; */
   background: green;
 }
.next-week:after {
 content:"";
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment as well, you just need to use the flex property of `justify-content` to align elements horizontally. In this case it will take the value of `flex-end` to align at the end.

```css
.next-week {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  background: green;
}

.next-week .next-icon {
  width: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.sche-content .next-week .next-icon p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="next-week">
  <div class="next-icon">
    <p>Next week</p>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```